# JDBI Fluent Query Issue

Tags: sql, dropwizard, jdbi

I'm using JDBI with Dropwizard and am having an issue with fluent queries. I have an api endpoint that looks like this:

```
public Response getAccount(@QueryParam("nickname") String nickname, @QueryParam("email") String email);
```

I'm trying to have to avoid writing the following 3 queries:

```
@SqlQuery(  " SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE EMAIL = :email "  )

public Account getAccountByEmail(@Bind("email") String email);


@SqlQuery( " SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE NICKNAME = :nickname " )

public Account getAccountByNickname(@Bind("nickname") String nickname);


@SqlQuery( " SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE NICKNAME = :nickname AND EMAIL = :email "  )

public Account getAccount(@Bind("nickname") String nickname, @Bind("email") String email);
```

This also means that my implementation for the method getAccount has 3 if checks... nickname and no email, email and no nickname, email and nickname, to determine which of the 3 queries to run. If I were to add another lookup parameter (accountId for example) this would mean I would now need to have 6 queries (1 for each possibility) and 6 if statements to determine which query to run.

Is there an easy way to get around this with JDBI? I've looked into the @Define possibility however this presents the risk of SQL Injection. Email and Nickname are both strings.

I would ideally only need one query:

```
@SqlQuery( " SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE NICKNAME = :nickname AND EMAIL = :email "  )

public Account getAccount(@Bind("nickname") String nickname, @Bind("email") String email);
```

If nickname was null it would ignore the nickname requirement and just query off the email. Is something like this possible?

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

I have now done this in order to clean up my code a bit:

```
    @SqlQuery(" SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE <query> ")
    public Account getAccount(@Bind("id") Long id, @Bind("nickname") String nickname, @Bind("email") String email, @Define("query") String query);
```

I've updated my JDBI dao to use @Define. By doing this I can cut my 6 queries (1 query per case as there are 3 query fields), and 6 if statements down to 1 query and 3 if statements.

```
    Account account = null;
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

    if(accountId != null) {
        query.append(" ID = :id ");
    }
    if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(nickname)) {
        if(query.length() > 0) query.append(" AND ");
        query.append(" NICKNAME = :nickname ");
    }
    else if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(email)) {
        if(query.length() > 0) query.append(" AND ");
        query.append(" EMAIL = :email ");
    }

    account = accountDAO.getAccount(accountId, nickname, email, query.toString());
```

I'd rather not have to use define though as I'd like to keep my querying logic in the DAO. It would be nice if something like this was at all possible:

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE @IfNotNull(id = :id) 
AND @IfNotNull(email = :email) AND @IfNotNull(nickname = :nickname)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this also in the single query instead of constructing sql in java code. Little hacky though.

```
select * from account where
( COALESCE(:email, NULL) IS NULL OR email = :email) and
( COALESCE(:nickname, NULL) IS NULL OR nickname = :nickname) ;
```

Comment: Good idea, but technically you should use (coalesce(:email, '') = '' OR email = :email) to match bcam909's if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(email)). Same with the nickname.

Comment: This would work if both email and nickname weren't null. If both nickname and email were null it would return all accounts. I'd have to add a check before calling this query to make sure nickname and email were both not null or empty.